# Constant accuracy while training the AlexNet model

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have been using this implementation of AlexNet Training I found on Github.
I have 8 input classes. Each class contains some images (Ex class1 : Bear, Class2 : Tiger; Class3: Horse ...) 
The problem is when I run the following code I saw that the Training accuracy is always equal to 1 divided by the number of class (in this case Training Accuracy = 0.125, If I have only 2 classes the training accuracy will be equal to 0.5)

I found this really weird and I could not figure out where is the mistake in the following code :

```
    from importData import Dataset
    import inference
    training = Dataset('wxb_pic/pic', '.jpg')
    testing = Dataset('wxb_pic/pic_test', '.jpg')
    import tensorflow as tf
    # Parameters
    learn_rate = 0.001
    decay_rate = 0.1
    batch_size = 64
    display_step = 20
    n_classes = training.num_labels # we got mad kanji
    dropout = 0.8 # Dropout, probability to keep units
    imagesize = 227
    img_channel = 3

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, imagesize, imagesize, img_channel])
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes])
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32) # dropout (keep probability)

    pred = inference.alex_net(x, keep_prob, n_classes, imagesize, img_channel)
    cost =tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y))

    global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
    lr = tf.train.exponential_decay(learn_rate, global_step, 1000, decay_rate, staircase=True)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=lr).minimize(cost, global_step=global_step)

    correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    tf.add_to_collection("x", x)
    tf.add_to_collection("y", y)
    tf.add_to_collection("keep_prob", keep_prob)
    tf.add_to_collection("pred", pred)
    tf.add_to_collection("accuracy", accuracy)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        step = 1
        while step < 3000:
            batch_ys, batch_xs = training.nextBatch(batch_size)

            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y: batch_ys, keep_prob: dropout})
            if step % display_step == 0:
                acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y: batch_ys, keep_prob: 1.})
                loss = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y: batch_ys, keep_prob: 1.})
                rate = sess.run(lr)
                print "lr " + str(rate) + " Iter " + str(step) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + "{:.6f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + "{:.5f}".format(acc)

           if step % 1000 == 0:
               saver.save(sess, 'save/model.ckpt', global_step=step*batch_size)
           step += 1
    print "Optimization Finished!"
    step_test = 1
    while step_test * batch_size < len(testing):
        testing_ys, testing_xs = testing.nextBatch(batch_size)
        print "Testing Accuracy:", sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: testing_xs, y: testing_ys, keep_prob: 1.})
        step_test += 1
```

I am Stuck with this and I want to train the AlexNet model to test the Performance of my machine.
Thanks ^^

Comment: Just to make sure I understood what is going on correctly: you found someone's implementation of some NN model on github. It does not work at all and you want SO people to fix this. Am I right?

Comment: Hi @SalvadorDali.
the model is working but the output is weird, by curiosity I tried to understand what makes the output look like this but I did not figure it out yet, that's why I asked for help, to have a discussion about it

Comment: based on my understanding if the model gives you the accuracy close to a random guess, this means that the model does not work. Also the questions about someone's else github code is most appropriate to address to a person who wrote that code through github